# Why would number of files recovered not match number deleted?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery

I am overly tired and accidentally pressed shift-delete on the wrong folder, and thus deleted it and all it's contents.  The progress message box said that 225 files were being deleted.

Without doing anything else, I ***immediately*** ran the portable versions of Wise Data Recovery and Recuva.  I was surprised to see that Wise Data Recovery could only find about 120 files and Recuva could only find 217 files.

Outside of the operating system itself (Windows 7 SP1), there were no applications running.

I figured that in the few seconds it took to load the recovery applications, maybe the operating system overwrote some of the files.  But Recuva includes a comprehensive list of every recently deleted file, even those that have been overwritten (it even tells the user what file is now occupying those clusters).  Recuva did not show any files from that folder (or its subfolders) that had been overwritten.

So why did the data recovery tools not find all the deleted files?

Comment: The simplest explanation, is some of the files, were already overwritten or partially overwritten.  Most file recovery software is smart enough to only recovery complete files it detects.  **Yes** This is still true even if it was immediate, Windows does a great number of things in the background, the files that were not recovered could have been on a sector that was immediately used..

Comment: Recuva isn't a perfect piece of software, so its inability to find traces of a deleted file, isn't an indication of anything specific.  It can only tell if a file was overwritten, if it can detect other blocks of that same file, if there are no other blocks then it wouldn't know.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the comments.  Even if unrecoverable, isn't there still a pointer for the deleted file in the file system (until that pointer is eventually replaced with one for a new file)?

Comment: "isn't there still a pointer for the deleted file in the file system " - This isn't always the case